# Action Method Should Hit For Particular Links Only

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

How to make action methods should hit for perticular links only,

it should not call another way.

Answer (score 1):

Create Custom Authorization for checking that the request is send by authorize action link or button.

to do so,

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AuthorizationForAction : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
              //your custom logic to authorize your action
        }
}
```

and use AuthorizationForAction tag over your specific action on controller